# Hide vue router from a page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to hide the vue-router from my login page? If so, how would I do that? On every page I have I see the menu, but on the Login page I don't want to see it.

Here is my code:

Login

```
 <template>
 <div>
     <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="">
            <label>naam</label>
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>


<style scoped>
    h1 {
        background-color: chartreuse;
    }
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="routing">

    </div>
    <router-link to="/">Login</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
    <router-view v-if="$route = 'login'"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Main.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import Login from './Login.vue'
    import Home from './Home.vue'

    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: Login},
        { path: '/home', component: Home},
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes,
        mode: 'history'
    });

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
        router,
      render: h => h(App)
    });
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <hr>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>


<style scoped>
h1 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had the same problem and found 2 approaches:

**1. Using nested routes - http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html**

Basically you have to use your App.vue as kind of a placeholder, with all the elements that are shared between all the pages (in your case I believe that is none), and place `<router-view></router-view>` inside it. For you I believe that will be as simples as:

```
//App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

And you also will have to have another template that will hold your menu:

```
//Restricted.vue

<template>
  <div id="restricted">
    <div class="routing">

    </div>
    <router-link to="/">Login</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in your router should have something like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import Login from './Login.vue'
import Home from './Home.vue'
import Restricted from '/.Restricted.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Login},
    {
        path: '/restricted',
        component: Restricted,
        children: [
           { path: 'home', component: Home},
        ],
    },        
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

This way your Login page will be rendered at `/` and other pages (with menu) at `/restricted/{other_page}`. Using this approach the menu will not be displayed nor rendered.

**2. Using `v-if` on the components that you do not want to render.**

In you `App.vue` use `v-if="this.$route.path !== '/'"` on the elements that you do not want to be rendered, in your case, the `router-link`'s. You could encapsulate them and apply `v-if="this.$route.path !== '/'"` to the encapsulation element (`div`?)

```
//App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="routing" v-if="this.$route.path !== '/'">
        <router-link to="/">Login</router-link>
        <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
    </div>

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `v-if` for this:

```
<router-link v-if="!isOnLoginPage()" to="/">Login</router-link>
```

where `isOnLoginPage` can be a simple method, which returns true or false depending on current route.

```
isOnLoginPage: function() {
  return this.$route.path === '/'
}
```

Comment: Will that hide the menu on the login page?

Comment: Ahh it should be opposite of it, I have modified the v-if condition now.

Comment: You know what I mean right? Hide the list with Login, Home etc. And for my menu on Home, Login shouldnt be in there.

Answer (score 0):

if your login path is '/login'

in your App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="routing">

    </div>
    <router-link to="/" v-if="$route.fullPath !== '/login'">Login</router-link>
    <router-link to="/home" v-if="$route.fullPath !== '/login'">Home</router-link>
    <router-view v-if="$route.fullPath === '/login'"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```